# Need to run test suites on different platforms

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

As part of our Pipeline i need to run tests on Linux, Windos & MAC. is there any built in option or best practices for such task? any examples?

I am expecting if there is any feasible inbuilt option in pipeline to achieve this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matrix step type in pipelines can be used here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Matrix by passing the nodepool options as part of stepletMutipliers.
sample step:

```
steps:
- name: step_1
  type: Matrix
  stepMode: Bash
  configuration:
    multiNode: true
  stepletMultipliers:
    environmentVariables:
      - foo: foo
      - bar: bar
    nodePools:
      - winNodePool
      - u20NodePool
```